# Duplicate entry error while I'm using unique validation

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, try-catch

I'm using unique validation and everything is OK when I test it but in laravel.log there are two integrity constraint violation error for that function like this (duplicate entry '5820103149' for key 'users_national_code_unique').

Validation works fine in tests. This is the store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = User::rules();
    unset($rules['completed_documents']);
    unset($rules['type_id']);
    $rules['account_number'] = 'required|string|unique:users,account_number';
    $rules['city_id'] = 'required|integer|exists:cities,id';
    $rules['address'] = 'nullable|string|min:20|max:200';
    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $request->merge([
        'type_id' => User::TYPES['phoenix'],
        'status' => User::STATUS['pending'],
        'password' => str_random(12),
    ]);
    $user = User::create($request->only([
        'gender',
        'name',
        'family',
        'national_id',
        'mobile',
        'address',
        'account_number',
        'city_id',
        'password',
        'status',
        'type_id',
    ]));

    if (in_array($user->typeLabel, ['hp', 'qudy'])) {
        $user->assignRole($user->typeLabel);
    }

    return response()->json($user, 201);
}
```

And this is the validation rules (shortened):

```
public static function rules($id = null)
{
    $rules = [
        'national_id'   => [
            'required',
            'digits:10',
            'unique:users,national_id',
            new Nationalcode
        ],
        'completed_documents'   => 'required|integer|in:0,1',
        'birth_city_id'         => 'nullable|integer|exists:cities,id',
        'account_number'        => 'nullable|string|unique:users,account_number',
    ];

    if ($id) {
        $rules['national_id'] = [
            'required',
            'digits:10',
            'unique:users,national_id,' . $id,
            new Nationalcode
        ];
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

The error:

```
    [2019-04-12 19:26:54] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5820103149' for key 'users_national_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`meta`, `history`, `gender`, `name`, `family`, `national_id`, `mobile`, `address`, `account_number`, `city_id`, `password`, `status`, `type_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ({}, {}, 1, ح*****ن, ع***ب, 5***149, 0*****9, شهرستان جویب****ستان, 6037****8901522, 180, $2y$10$fSLw0o8J1JkVWKBWLQ7m3eQQQQiByk.7beRf4vQrcB3Wbb38IpJEu, 2, 3, 2019-04-12 19:26:54, 2019-04-12 19:26:54)) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5820103149' for key 'users_national_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`meta`, `history`, `gender`, `name`, `family`, `national_id`, `mobile`, `address`, `account_number`, `city_id`, `password`, `status`, `type_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ({}, {}, 1, ح****ن, ع***ب, 5820103149, 09337956089, شهرستان جو******ان, 6037997298901522, 180, $2y****w0o8J1JkVWKB******vQrcB3Wbb38IpJEu, 2, 3, 2019-04-12 19:26:54, 2019-04-12 19:26:54)) at /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5820103149' for key 'users_national_id_unique' at /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:119, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5820103149' for key 'users_national_id_unique' at /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `us...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #1 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(459): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('insert into `us...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #2 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(411): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->statement('insert into `us...', Array)
    #3 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php(32): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->insert('insert into `us...', Array)
    #4 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2494): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Processors\\Processor->processInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder), 'insert into `us...', Array, 'id')
    #5 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1283): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
    #6 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(787): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
    #7 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(752): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder), Array)
    #8 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(615): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder))
    #9 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(755): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->save()
    #10 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1041): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\{closure}(Object(App\\Models\\User))
    #11 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(756): tap(Object(App\\Models\\User), Object(Closure))
    #12 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1570): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->create(Array)
    #13 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1582): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->__call('create', Array)
    #14 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php(43): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::__callStatic('create', Array)
    #15 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\UserController->store(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #16 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #17 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('store', Array)
    #18 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\UserController), 'store')
    #19 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
    #20 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(665): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
    #21 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #22 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/app/Http/Middleware/CheckUserStatus.php(28): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #23 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): App\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckUserStatus->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #24 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #25 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #26 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #27 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #28 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(67): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #29 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #30 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #31 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #32 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #33 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #34 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #35 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #36 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #37 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #38 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #39 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #40 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #41 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #42 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #43 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #44 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(667): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #45 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(642): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #46 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(608): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
    #47 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(597): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #48 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #49 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #50 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(58): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #51 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #52 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #53 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/app/Http/Middleware/PreferredDomain.php(32): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #54 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): App\\Http\\Middleware\\PreferredDomain->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #55 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #56 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/app/Http/Middleware/ModifyRequest.php(51): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #57 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): App\\Http\\Middleware\\ModifyRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #58 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #59 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #60 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #61 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #62 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #63 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #64 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #65 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #66 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #67 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #68 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #69 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #70 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #71 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #72 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #73 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #74 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #75 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #76 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #77 /home/quantum/web/quantumco.ir/public_html/app/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #78 {main}
    "}
```

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: @PowerStat Here you are. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Could you log the sql statements that will be send to the database?

Comment: @PowerStat Sorry I forgot it!

Comment: Looks like you use insert's all the time - so if the data is already within the database an insert for the same dataset will fail - for this case you need to update the data. Another reason might be that there are really datasets with the same users_national_id_unique - but I don't think so.

Comment: @PowerStat Thanks, would you please tell me how can I "update the data"?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know laravel - I nowadays work with Java and Hibernate - my PHP times (for larger projects) ended somewhere around 2005 ....

Answer (score 0):

You have to ignore self to prevent this error:

```
'FIELD' => 'unique:table,email_column_to_check,id_to_ignore'
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's a store method not an update method